# Need help iterating throw a directory of fits files and extracting filter name from fits header

Tags: astropy

As the title states, I'm trying to go through a directory of HST image fits files, and extract the filter of the image from the fits header.

[image: Image with code]

When I run the following for an individual image, I am able to obtain the filter name (the second block of code in the image), but when I attempt to iterate through the directory, I get an error message stating that there is no such keyword as "filter", which I don't understand, because clearly each image has filter information in the header. I would greatly appreciate your help in iterating through the directory and getting filter information for each image. Thanks!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: "because clearly each image has filter information in the header": clearly, it does not. If you think the offending FITS file does have the information in the header, please point us to the relevant FITS file (jcz802biq_flc.fits, in so far I decipher the impossible-to-read-properly image-of-code).

Comment: So one file in the directory had a FILTER header in the primary HDU and another didn't. You can check this on each file by iterating over the HDUs and asking `if 'FILTER' in hdu.header`. IIRC many HST data products, depending on the instrument and/or when it was produced don't put any data in the primary HDU which just contains some metadata, and then the actual CCD data for example in an IMAGE extension.